# How to build Boost.MPI under Buildroot?

Tags: boost, buildroot, boost-mpi

By default, package `BR2_PACKAGE_BOOST_MPI` does not build when cross-compiling in [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/): It requires detecting MPI (e.g. OpenMPI) configuration and libraries, and given this is not possible automatically (in the buildroot environment), the `bjam` build system will just inform Boost.MPI gets skipped:

```
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
```

In my environment I was able to workaround this by patching `output/build/boost-1.61.0/user-config.jam`:

```
using gcc : 6.2.0 : 
     /home/me/buildroot-2016.11/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-g++ : 
     <cxxflags>"-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Os " <linkflags>"" ;

using mpi : /home/me/buildroot-2016.11/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/g++ : 
<find-shared-library>mpi  <find-shared-library>dl ;
```

(the first line is the only contents of `user-config.jam` as configured by the build system; I added the second line. Also, paths were adapted here).

*Note: I obtained that bjam line by looking at [mpi.jam](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_43_0/tools/build/v2/tools/mpi.jam) sources and lots of trial an error.*

However, any clean rebuild will delete `output/build` directory, thus wiping these changes.

Is there a "correct" way of enabling compilation of Boost.MPI when crosscompiling with Buildroot? Or at least, being able to patch the `user-config.jam` file after the build system configures the compiler? (note that paths depend on my system configuration and target host).

Comment: Seems like you just need to tweak `boost.mk` and add needed string to `user-config.jam` and perhaps add dependency for openmpi. Though I'd still suggest to post this question to BR's mailing list.